# Command cooldown for everyone not for each user

Tags: discord.js

I want to make cooldown on a command, cooldown has to work for everyone.

```
//Start of code or something
var cooldowns = {}
var minute = 60000;
var hour = minute * 24;

//Set cooldown
cooldowns[message.author.id] = Date.now() + hour * 24; //Set a 24 hour cooldown

//At command check
if(cooldowns[message.author.id]){
     if(cooldowns[message.author.id] > Date.now()) delete cooldowns[message.author.id];
     else console.log("user still has " + Math.round((cooldowns[message.author.id] - Date.now)/minute) + " minutes left"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Discord.collection` for this

This [guide](https://discordjs.guide/command-handling/adding-features.html#cooldowns), describes how yo set cooldown per user, but all whats you need its channge `message.author.id` to `message.guild.id`